# Encapsulation and Exceptions

Tags: exception, language-design, encapsulation, language-theory

I'm designing my own OO language and was happily going along until I hit exceptions. It seems to me that exceptions break encapsulation.

For example, if class A has an object of class B, B has C, and C has X, which throws an exception to A, the code in A must not only know about X but also B and C to handle it correctly. You can tell this because if you replace C with D, A exception's handler will have to change to extract the relevant information from the call stack.

The only way I can think of around this problem is to have exceptions as part of the class' API so that they propagate back up the calling stack one caller at a time. And they should re-interrupt the exception in their own terms.

Here's an example. Trend is a class for analyzing statistical trends and it has a method, slope, for calculating the slope of a line from two points.

```
method slope
    given
        Point 1st
        Point 2nd
    returns
        Number m
    except
        when infinite slope

    m gets
        ( 2nd's y - 1st's y ) / ( 2nd's x - 1st's x )
    except
        when any divide by zero
            declare infinite slope
        when overflow of ( 2nd's y - 1st's y )
            declare infinite slope
        when overflow of ( 2nd's x - 1st's x )
            instead do m gets 0
        when overflow of ( 2nd's y - 1st's y ) / ( 2nd's x - 1st's x )
            declare infinite slope
        when any underflow
            instead use 0

end of method slope
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but what language is this?

Comment: Very first line: I'm designing my own OO language...

Answer (score 2):

Real-world exceptions fall into one of three rough categories:

- System exceptions are thrown when fatal errors in the underlying runtime occur, things like out of memory, stack overflow, or perhaps security violations. These generally shouldn't be caught, and in many cases *can't* be caught. They basically use the exception system in order to take down the system (relatively) gracefully and report the final stack trace to the developer.
- Programmatic exceptions are thrown when the code is doing something incorrect. Things like invalid arguments, calling methods on null pointers, out of bounds errors. These shouldn't be caught: instead the code that causes them to be thrown should be fixed. They use the exception system to avoid having a more or less redundant `assert` system that does most of the same things.
- Runtime exceptions are thrown when something bad happens that cannot be programmatically prevented. They are thrown when an unexpected circumstance has occurred, but its rare enough that you don't want to clutter up the main API with error codes, etc. These are things like file IO errors, network problems, parse errors, etc. These exceptions will usually be specific to the API that's throwing them. These are the *only* kind of exceptions that should be typically caught.

If you agree with the above breakdown, then encapsulation only effects the third category. For the other two, the exception isn't caught in code, so it doesn't matter. For the third kind of exception, yes, I think you generally should catch the exception and translate it to different exception that's appropriate the layer that's rethrowing it. This is why most exception systems in other languages support something like "InnerException" where you can attach the previous lower-level exception that led to the current one.

Comment: Since the third case is the only one that should be caught and it's only used to write cleaner code, then it's a goto. It seems to me that there is another possibility; that an exception can be used to signal that a transaction cannot be completed and the rest of the code is to clean up any changes it made for the transaction so that the application will return to its previous valid state.

Answer (score 0):

> if you replace C with D, A exception's
>   handler will have to change to extract the relevant information from
>   the call stack.

Not the way exception handlers are usually implemented. The intermediate called classes may not even exist when A is compiled, so building that dependency into A is not only hard but in principle infeasible.

Comment: So if X throws, "File not found," A has no idea why the file is needed in the first place and can only report to the user, "File not found" and the user has to pour through the documentation for an explanation? That doesn't sound to me like a good way to win friends and influence people.

Comment: @shawnhcorey The relationship, if any, between what I have written above and whatever it is you're talking about now, escapes me completely. This is a complete *non sequitur.* The requirement to generate code that will cope with as-yet unwritten intermediate calling code remains. C++ does it for example: it is clearly not impossible.

Comment: It's possible to write the whole thing in machine code; it's just not advisable. The question is not what's possible, or what others have done. It's what's best.

Comment: @shawnhcorey Once again I don't know what you're talking about. C++ was cited as a counterexample that disproves your apparent misconception that you need to have the intermediate classes avaialable at compile time to generate an exception handler. You don't need them, and in the general case you can't have them for the reason I have given. You don't appear to even acknowledge the existence of the problem of classes which haven't been written yet, and you appear to be already fixated on some solution that cannot cope with them. You need to rethink.

Comment: Writing exception handlers for classes that don't exist is guessing. And guessing leads to bugs. You're correct; I'm not interested in creating another PHP. Each new language is suppose to be better than those before.

Comment: @shawnhcorey Designing software to solve real-world problems and to operate within its actual real-world constraints is in this case not guesswork but compiler engineering. The problem exists whether you accept it or not, and the problem constrains the possible solutions. Compilers have to be designed to generate code that will work with other code that isnt available at compile time. You don't seem to even understand that, let alone be interested in a constructive dialog.

Comment: Oh, I understand the problem: if the APIs is not rigorously designed, then the pieces won't work together. What you're saying is that most exceptions are very superficial since only the simplest form of APIs will work. Not surprising; they don't teach the important of interface design in school and real-world practice seems to be creating the most bugs in the least amount of time. Not to worry, I'm thinking of reject exceptions completely since a superficial exception is little more than a cleverly-disguised goto.

Comment: @shawnhcorey Continually putting words into my mouth, or raising peripheral issues such as machine code, PHP, or exceptions being superficial', whatever that means, or API design, doesn't demonstrate any understanding whatsoever. I've said several times that it's not clear what exactly you are talking about, which you haven't addressed. I repeat: (1) 'code in A must not only know about X but also B and C to handle it correctly' is demonstrably false by counterexample, and (2) requiring all the source code to be available at compile time is in general not feasible, however desirable to you.

Comment: (1) My question is not about what's possible but what's best. Everything else is off topic.

Answer (score 0):

Im agree that Exceptions sounds more Structured that Object-and-Class-Oriented.

However, allow to solve dealing with errors.

*For example, ... 
... to extract the relevant information from the call stack.*

Your example in C++ -like **pseudocode**:

```
class XClass {
  public: 
    void doSomething() { throw new MyException(); }
}

class CClass {
  public: 
    XClass X;
}

class BClass {
  public: 
    CClass C;
}

class AClass {
  public: 
    BClass B;
}

void main()
{
  AClass A = new AClass ();

  // exception here:
  A.B.C.X.doSomething();
}
```

"A" object doesn't have to know about "X", or viceversa, regarding exceptions. There should be an exception stack, which, all objects add or remove execution data.

"pure C" doesn't have exceptions, but, they can be emulated. You may want to search for the "setjmp" library, and see can those functions interact with the stack. Those knowledge may help you implement exceptions:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/csetjmp/

P.D. Offtopic suggestion: add c++ namespaces, or pascal modules, to your progr. lang., you won't regret it.

Comment: This `A.B.C.X.doSomething();` states that whatever calls A must know about X. It just pushes the problem up one level. :(

Comment: @shawnhcorey No, means, "A" method stores data into stack, "B" method stores data into stack, "C" method stores data into stack, "X" method stores data into stack, and the exception handler detects an error, and instead of using that data, to go to next instruction, throws an exception.